# How to get "error" message from @commands.has_role()

Tags: python, error-handling, bots, discord, discord.py

I recently made a discord bot using discord.py. I tried making permissions for some commands. I have this test command function:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Moderator')
async def cool(ctx):
    await ctx.send("You are cool indeed!")
```

How can I return a message(error) when a user does not have the 'Moderator' role?

I've already tried this:

```
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
        await ctx.send("*Private messages.* ")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("*Command is missing an argument:* ")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.DisabledCommand):
        await ctx.send("*This command is currenlty disabled. Please try again later.* ")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("*You do not have the permissions to do this.* ")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("*This command is not listed in my dictionary.*")
```

But I'm not getting anything back from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `on_command_error` function, check against [`commands.MissingRole`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingRole) or [`commands.MissingAnyRole`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingAnyRole).

```
if isinstance(error, (commands.MissingRole, commands.MissingAnyRole)):
    ...
```